# List with string array (List<string[]>)

Tags: c#, arrays, string, list

I have some strange problem where all my string arrays has the same value in the List.
Here is my code:

```
List<string[]> map_data = new List<string[]>();
string[] map_data_array = new string[11];

for(int i = 0; i < 2000; i++)
{
    map_data_array = PopulateDataFromFile(); // it returns different data every call
    map_data.Add(map_data_array); // store to List
}
```

map_data_array has always different data, I've verified that by placing the break point there and I've checked it.

The problem is that `map_data` has the value of all elements the same. And this value is the data that comes from function `PopulateDataFromFile` when the i is 1999.

What I am doing wrong? :/

Comment: post the code for `PopulateDataFromFile()` as well

Comment: in the immediate window try this `map_data[0] == map_data[1999]` if it returns `true` you are adding the same array 2000 times (that is `PopulateDataFromFile()` returns the same array if it returns `false` then `PopulateDataFromFile()` returns a new array every time but with the4 same content

Comment: @Golgauth please don't add tags to title, it was removed for a purpose. Also don't use inline code to mark every keyword in the post it's creating too much "noise".

Comment: Check one more thing while you debug - in the second iteration when you see map_data_array has returned different values, check that map_data[0] would also have the same value. That means somewhere your code is updating same reference.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Ok, noted for the inline code, I will never do this again, I promise ;-) But I never changed the title...

Comment: @Golgauth fair enough, but the second part in my comment still stands.

Comment: `PopulateDataFromFile();` is returning everything in one go and the array is storing as much as it can, e.g. the first 12 elements. See my answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That only happens if you place the same array into the list. As you did not give the code to `PopulateDataFromFile` we can only guess what happens. Make sure that the function returns a seperate array created with `new` each time.

Comment: Thank you, I got declared "map_data_array" on the "global" scope.

Comment: But why this happens? Do the list actually "link" the object and not save/copy the data that this object has?

Comment: @tilenslo This is happening because `PopulateDataFromFile();` is probably returning the same data on each iteration.

Comment: Yep! That's a good synthesis, regarding the few intell we have here.

Comment: @DGibbs Not the same data. It looks like it returns the same array, but each time with different data.

Comment: @svick `it returns the same array, but each time with different data.` how could it look like the same array then? If it returns the same array then it must have the same data to be considered `the same`. The OP even states that the data is all the same: `I have some strange problem where all my string arrays has the same value in the List`

Comment: @DGibbs You call `PopulateDataFromFile()` once and it returns an array with some data. You call it for the second time, it takes the same array, changes the data and returns that. So, if you look at the array `PopulateDataFromFile()` returned right after it returns, it looks like it's returning different data each time. But it's actually returning the same array every time, so if you look at the list after the loop, you will see the same data over and over (because it's the same array).

Comment: @svick Hmmm ` So, if you look at the array PopulateDataFromFile() returned right after it returns, it looks like it's returning different data each time.` why am I having a hard time believing this?  Since we don't have concrete code for the method we can only speculate as to its implementation.

Comment: @DGibbs Because that's what the question says: “map_data_array has always different data, I've verified that by placing the break point there and I've checked it.”

Comment: @svick right, perhaps he means the data inside of the array is all the same rather than all the arrays all contain the same data. It's a bit ambiguous.

Answer (score 1):

You need to process your data in chunks since `PopulateDataFromFile();` looks to be returning all of its data in one go (or as much as the array can fit). Using an extension method, you could do something like this: -

```
List<string[]> map_data = new List<string[]>();
foreach (var batch in PopulateDataFromFile().Batch(11))
{
       map_data.Add((batch.ToArray());
}
```

Extension method: -

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> Batch<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items, int batchSize)
{
     return items.Select((item, inx) => new { item, inx })
                 .GroupBy(x => x.inx / batchSize)
                 .Select(g => g.Select(x => x.item));
}
```

Comment: I really don't see how is processing in chunks going to help. And why 11? Why not 10000000?

Comment: Probably has something to do with: `string[] map_data_array = new string[11];`... Looks to me like `PopulateDataFromFile();` could be returning everything, feel free to disagree though :)

Comment: Right, I didn't realize that. But that means your code makes even *less* sense, since it's always going to return a single batch.

Comment: ??? How so? Consider a collection size of 2000. On what planet would it return a single batch?

Comment: I assumed `PopulateDataFromFile()` always returns a 11-element array. But in any case, i still don't see any situation where batching the data could fix the issue.

Comment: You know what they say about assuming

Answer (score 0):

PopulateDataFromFile() is returning a String array with the same values.

Comment: The question says differently: “map_data_array has always different data”.

Answer (score -5):

In the loop everytime you just change the address of map_data_array , so that's why always the value will get changed to the newer data obtained from the method call. Reinitialize the string array everytime will help. It should look something like this

```
    for(int i = 0; i < 2000; i++)
    {
         string[] map_data_array = PopulateDataFromFile(); // it returns different data every call
         map_data.Add(map_data_array); // store to List
    }
```

or if its confusing for you can you make it simple by

```
    for(int i = 0; i < 2000; i++)
    {             
         map_data.Add(PopulateDataFromFile()); // store to List
    }
```

Comment: i don't understand the answers here... it's essentially the same as what the OP does.

Comment: Sorry, that's wrong. Only the return value of the function decides what gets stored in the list, no matter what variable you store it in temporarily (as long as you don't make copies).

Comment: Are you saying that if you declare `map_data_array` outside the loop and then change it, the value in the list will also change? That's certainly not true.

Comment: That doesn't change anything. The declaration does not determine the storage location, only `new` does.

Comment: yes understood , you have to make sure that the return value from the method (PopulateDataFromFile) is always a new object instead of just changing the existing object.